# Handling Modal Dialogs with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium to automate a process and the page I want to interact to opens a modal dialog every time someone access it. I want to be able to interact with the main page properly, so I need a way to close the dialog. However, I've tried some suggestions on handling modal dialogs and they are not working as they should. There are two buttons I can click on to close the dialog, one of them is:

```
  <div class="modal-footer"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button> 
  </div>
```

I've tried to locate this button and then click on it with:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Fechar")
test.click()
```

But this is not closing the dialog. Using:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Fechar")
test.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

gives me the following error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Fechar"}.
```

I've also thought of writing a script to navigate through the dialog using the TAB key and then hitting Enter when the close button is reached. But I don't know if this the proper way to handle the problem and if this can be done without issues. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With find_element_by_link_text method, you won't find a button, you will find a link element (a). [Reference](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text).

If you want to get that button, you could use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.modal-footer > button[data-dismiss="modal"]')
```